# Checkout Step Navigation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

i have no idea how to solve this Problem.
I have 4 Checkout Steps. Each Step has an Form to fullfill.
If Form is valid, the next Step in Navigation should be activated.

This is the Routing Script

```
"use strict";

var router = angular.module("router", ["ui.router"]);
router.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "$locationProvider", "$httpProvider",
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: true,
      rewriteLinks: true
    });

    $stateProvider
      .state("step1", {
        url: "/step1",
        controller: "Step1Controller",
        templateUrl: "app/views/step1-partial.html"
      })
      .state("step2", {
        url: "/step2",
        controller: "Step2Controller",
        templateUrl: "app/views/step2-partial.html"
      })
      .state("step3", {
        url: "/step3",
        controller: "Step3Controller",
        templateUrl: "app/views/step3-partial.html"
      })
      .state("step4", {
        url: "/step4",
        controller: "Step4Controller",
        templateUrl: "app/views/step4-partial.html"
      });
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/step1");
  }
]);

router.run(function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
  $rootScope.$state = $state;
  $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
});
```

and this is one of the Partials View

```
<section class="steps">
  <ul class="clear-list">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Step1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Step2</a></i></li>
    <li><a href="#">Step3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Step4</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>

<form name="registerForm" ng-cloak>
  formfields...
</form>

<div class="step-footer">
  <a href="#" ng-class="{'disable-link' : registerForm.$invalid}" ng-click="processData()" class="step-button right">Next ></a>
</div>
```

can somebody help me out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In processData() function (which i am hoping you will we having in all three controllers) after successful processing of data you can do `$location.path('/step2');` 
and so on for all the steps.

For activating the current section in which currently you are, you can have some common variable in all three controller and set the value of that variable like **($scope.currentStep = step1)** respectively.
Example.

```
<section class="steps">
  <ul class="clear-list">
    <li ng-class="{active : currentStep=='step1'}"><a href="#">Step1</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{active : currentStep=='step2'}"><a href="#">Step2</a></i></li>
    <li ng-class="{active : currentStep=='step3'}"><a href="#">Step3</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{active : currentStep=='step4'}"><a href="#">Step4</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: ok, this works for. But i have one more Questions to this. I´m want to extend this to have the following behaviour.
if "step1" is fullfiled, "step2" is activated, and i can click it.
When i´m on "step2", "step1" should be active, too. When "step2" is fullfiled, i go to "step3", and "step1", "step2" are active,

Comment: @magic.77 for that case you can have an array for example. isCompleted = [true, false, false, false]  if you are in step 2 and replace in ng-class="{active: isCompleted[0]}" and so on. set this array accordingly in each controller.

Answer (score 0):

use `ui-sref-active="active"` instead of `class`